# Ubuntu systemctl - no more prompts please

Tags: ubuntu

How to stop this password prompt when starting service on ubuntu.

I just want it gone, for every systemctl service, forever.

````
mick@81774X:~$ systemctl start myservice
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'mysertvice.service'.
Authenticating as: mick,,, (mick)
Password: ```
````

Comment: Just use ... sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the superuser can manage services through the systemctl.
There is no way to remove this behavior, just workarounds.

The safest option: allow the superuser to execute the command without a password and use `sudo systemctl start myservice`

To do this, enter `sudo visudo` find the line `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` and add after it: `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl`
Save the file (by default `Ctrl+o` then `Enter` then `Ctrl+x`)
Now you can use the command `sudo systemctl start myservice` without password.